# Salesforce new formula field incorrect formula

Tags: salesforce

I created a new Formula field called "Short License Number" that will contain the following value:

In case "License Number" field is not empty, "Short License Number" field will contain "License Number" first left character. For example: "License Number" = 123456789 "Short License Number" = 1

I tried this and it's not working 
IF( ( ISBLANK(LicenseNumber__c ),true, LEFT(LicenseNumber__c , 1))
 this is returned to "Short License Number" field

I Want to know what I did wrong?

Thanks, Liraz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula looks wrong. Since u want to put the first char/number in case that the LicenseNumber__c field is NOT empty u have to do the following:

```
IF( NOT(ISBLANK(LicenseNumber__c)), VALUE(LEFT(LicenseNumber__c, 1)), VALUE(NULL))
```

In my case new created formula field is an Number formula field and the LicenseNumber__c field is a text field. Thats why I use the VALUE expression.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it's help !